# Concatenated where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant get this SQL query to update my database activties table.  This is my query:-

```
UPDATE Activities 
SET  CJSID = CJSEmpNum.StaffNumber 
FROM CJSEmpNum 
Where Activites.Name = CJSEmpNum.Surname + " " + CJSEmpNum.Forename
```

I think my problem is the where clause.  In activities number Name is stored as Smith John and in CJSEmpNum it is stored in two seperate columns Surname and Forename.

Comment: `I think my problem is the where clause` ... it sure is, because your query can be SQL injected.  Please show us the actual code, not the extracted query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you sure about that? I'm not sure this question has anything to do with C# - it's quite unclear.

Comment: Is that purely sql, and not C#?  Please tag your question correctly.  Do you get any errors, or just 0 rows updated?  Can you do a `Select` to check the exact contents of `Activites.Name` and `CJSEmpNum.Surname + " " + CJSEmpNum.Forename`?

Comment: @DavidG Now you have me wondering myself.  Who knows what is being asked here /:-|

Comment: Sorry it is sql i clicked the wrong thing.

Comment: If this is pure T-SQL, the double quotes should be single quotes. Double quotes can only escape identifiers, and there is probably no column named " " (space).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Since this is pure SQL and not a dynamic generation of the statement, SQL injection doesn't apply here.

Comment: Check if  `CJSEmpNum.Surname` or `CJSEmpNum.Forename` has any space in it.

Comment: Tag your DBMS SqlServer/MySql/Oracle

Comment: Do you get any error when you execute this query?

Comment: no errors just didnt return anything

Comment: An update won't return anything except the number of rows affected.  The first answer should work in any of your data is a match for the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making this an inner join? Something like...

UPDATE 
    A
SET
    A.CJSID = CJSEmpNum.StaffNumber 
FROM 
    CJSEmpNum
INNER JOIN
    Activities  A ON A.Name = CJSEmpNum.Surname + ' '  + CJSEmpNum.Forename

Comment: You need a space between the single quotes in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UPDATE A 
SET  CJSID = C.StaffNumber 
FROM Activities A
INNER JOIN  CJSEmpNum C ON A.Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(C.Surname)) +' '+ RTRIM(LTRIM(C.Forename))
```